# Using Optional<T> from java SE 8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Hi I want to know how I can use Optional in java SE 8 in the function below.

```
public URL getAuthenticatedURL() throws MalformedURLException {
    if (log != null){
        log.writeINFOToLog("Fetching authentication URL...");
    }
    else{
        Log.initLog();
        log.writeINFOToLog("Fetching authentication URL...");
    }
    try{
        String url = String.format("%s://%s%s?username=%s&password=%s",getProtocol(), getHost(), getPath(), getUsername(), getPassword());
        URL returnURL = new URL(url);
        return returnURL;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex){
        log.writeExceptionToLog(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to handle the scenario where values involved in constructing the URL is null or empty.

Comment: Well, what do you want text to put in the URL if a value is indeed null or empty?

Comment: Good question. Just the hostname and no parameters.

Comment: What do your `getUsername()` and `getPassword()` return? I'm not seeing how `Optional` is going to help you here. You will still need to do a check from where where you do something like `optional.isPresent()` and then append it as a query parameter.

Comment: @Mike Kobit. So each of those functions will need to return Optional<String> ?

Comment: It really depends on how you want to model your data and how you want to build out your URL. Right now you do `String.format(...)` which assumes that both username and password will have some value for the query string. You could do a check before you append them like 'if (getUsername().isPresent()) { //add username}' if you wanted to model it that way.

Comment: Do you know about [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I think its best that I avoid nulls, since it does not make much sense to have a null.

Here is my code snippet of the same function once I have used `Optional<URL>`

```
public Optional<URL> getAuthenticatedURL() throws MalformedURLException {
    if (log != null){
        log.writeINFOToLog("Fetching authentication URL...");
    }
    else{
        Log.initLog();
        log.writeINFOToLog("Fetching authentication URL...");
    }
    String url = String.format("%s://%s%s?username=%s&password=%s",getProtocol(), getHost(), getPath(), getUsername(), getPassword());
    return Optional.ofNullable(new URL(url));
}
```

So when I call the function the code will be something like this.

```
if(getAuthenticatedURL.isPresent()){
  URL val = getAuthenticatedURL.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more reasonable to use **`Supplier`** than `Optional`, because `getAuthenticatedURL()` has no argument and generates an Object(URL).

It looks like:

```
Supplier<URL> supplier = () -> {
    ...
    try {
        return new URL(...);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    }
};
URL url = supplier.get();
```